# Execute commands in shell using root user

Tags: shell, drush

I am trying to execute a command in remote machine through shell script. That command needs to be executed as a root user. After logging in to remte machine with my normal ID, then execute the command(which is there is different path) in a specific path with root user. I am using below code

```
current_dir=$PWD;/usr/local/bin;sudo -u root drush data_export_import-export nodes --content-types=book;cd $current_dir;
```

i am getting below error

```
./test.sh: line 8: /usr/local/bin: is a directory
[sudo] password for s57232:
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
The drush command 'data_export_import-export nodes' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.                      [error]
```

It should not expect the password to be supplied and also drush command need to be executed from /usr/local/bin in /var/www/html path.

i tried below also but did not work

```
sudo -u root /var/www/html
sudo -u root /usr/local/bin/drush data_export_import-export nodes --content-types=book >> ${DATAPATH} 2>&1
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Your first error, at least, doesn't seem relevant. You just forgot to use `cd`: `cd /usr/local/bin/`. The other error would seem to be a `drush` configuration or installation problem, something I can't give any useful advice on.

Comment: command should execute at /var/www/html path. But that command is at /usr/local/bin. Hope I am clear. When I doing the same from commandline, I am able to. But through shell i am not able to.

Comment: Are you using the `autocd` option in your interactive shell? You would need to enable that explicitly in the script: `shopt -s autocd`.